# AstroでTailwindCSSとmdxを利用している中で通常のMarkdownの表示にしたい

Tags: javascript, markdown, tailwindcss

AstroとTailwindCSSにスタイルを設定したいが、分からない
とりあえず、CSSファイルなどを作成して当ててみたが効果なし

mdxファイル

```
---
layout: ../../components/BaseLayout.astro

title: '初めての投稿'

---


# 初めての投稿

特にない
テスト用
```

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に直接追記するのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。 (質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保つべきです)

Comment: じぶんであれやこれやしてたらできました
https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css
これのREADMEどうりに進めればできました

Comment: コメント欄ではなく「回答」として投稿してみてください。 参考: [自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)